# WIFI Connectivity Through Code

Tags: android, android-wifi

My phone is connected to wifi successfully. I need user of my app to connect phone with another wifi using app. My app will list all wifi ssid available and user has to select one out of it and has to enter password.

Is there a way within app to know if user entered the correct password for the wifi and when user enters wrong password for wifi?

Comment: You can [watch for a successful connection.](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring) But really, this question is very broad, not SO-like. Might want to narrow it down.

Comment: My requirement is to know if password entered for wifi is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver to check if you connection is successful or not:

```
new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch (intent.getAction()) {

                    case ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION:
                        if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
                            // Connected the right one

                            Log.show("Connected to Wifi: " + NetworkUtils.getConnectedWifiSsid(mContext));

                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Actually my question is how would I know in app code if wifi connection is successful or not?

Comment: Are isNetworkAvailable and getConnectedWifiSsid library methods? I can't see implementation for these methods.